# Initializing a nested object which contains an array

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I have an object which I need to populate with some data. But when I try to populate the Party, I get a null reference error.

The object: https://pastebin.pl/view/f9f34c0e (Basically an object with 2 objects that contain an array of other objects)

Initializing:

```cs
Models.InHouse.TestSpec.InhouseOrder io = new Models.InHouse.TestSpec.InhouseOrder {
Header = new Models.InHouse.TestSpec.InhouseOrderHeader { Party = new Models.InHouse.TestSpec.InhouseOrderHeaderParty[10] },
content = new Models.InHouse.TestSpec.InhouseOrderContent { Item = new Models.InHouse.TestSpec.InhouseOrderContentItem[100] }};
```

But when I try to access  `io.header.Party[0].ID` I get a Null Reference error. In the end, I will serialize it to a XML.

Comment: Try : if(io.header.Party[0] == null) io.header.Party[0] = new InhouseOrderHeaderParty();  You created an array of the parties but did not construct each individual party.

Comment: [ask], and [mre]. Question must be self containt. And all revelante code should not be hosted in 3rd party site. For null ref exception we have this big gide line https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it. And [Array Elements] part of the accepted answer address this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well when you initialize like:

```
Party = new Models.InHouse.TestSpec.InhouseOrderHeaderParty[10]
```

Now the `Party` is an array of `Models.InHouse.TestSpec.InhouseOrderHeaderParty` with capacity of 10, but these 10 array items has the default value of `Models.InHouse.TestSpec.InhouseOrderHeaderParty` which is null.

You can later do something like:

```
for(int i=0; i< Party.Length; i++)
    Party[i] = new Models.InHouse.TestSpec.InhouseOrderHeaderParty();
```

**Update (Based on your comment):**

You can intialize the array Items like:

```
Header = Enumerable.Range(1,10).Select(x => new Models.InHouse.TestSpec.InhouseOrderHeaderParty()).ToArray();
```

Comment: Thanks Ashkan. This works. Is there a way to initialize differently for the array items to have the default value of Models.InHouse.TestSpec.InhouseOrderHeaderParty?